# Counting a specific column's total values in my Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to get the **total** amount of values in the column *SellingPrice* in my `datagrid`. How would I go about counting the total amount in c# coding?

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemId}" Header="id" MinWidth="20" MaxWidth="100" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemCode}" Header="Code" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemDescription}" Header="Description" MinWidth="280" MaxWidth="360" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemSellingPrice}" Header="Selling Price" MinWidth="120" MaxWidth="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="QTY" MinWidth="120" MaxWidth="120" IsReadOnly="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

If you need any more information on my code/classes that I use, please feel free to ask. I will give it as soon as I can :) Thank you.

**EDIT** I want to display the *Total Amount* in a label

Comment: Get total amount but in what manner ? You want to have another column with sum of something or what ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I want to display the total amount in a label.

Comment: Just loop through the data source and sum ItemSellingPrice

Comment: Did You find your answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your View Model, create a read-only property:

```
public double SumOfSomething 
{
    get
    {
        return YourCollection.Sum(x => x.ItemSellingPrice);
    }
}
```

You can then bind a label to this property:

```
<label Content="{Binding SumOfSomething}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a List of items and bind that to the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid`. Furthermore I assume you have a `Label` named `_label`. Then your c# looks like:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public double ItemSellingPrice { get; set; }
    public int QTY { get; set; }
}

public class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var items = new List<Item>();
        _dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
        var totalAmount = items.Sum(i => i.ItemSellingPrice);
        _label.Content= totalAmount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct for no MVVM. +